# Width of Flexbox Columns not Shrinking on Window Resize

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm using Flexbox to make 5 boxes responsive when the browser window is shrunk. 4 of the boxes are in 2 columns and fail to shrink (`flex-direction: column`). The single box that is not in a column shrinks correctly.

(Bob is behaving correctly, but Kate, Nick, Jane and Fred refuse to reduce their width.)

How do I make the width of the columns shrink as the browser window size is reduced?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.big {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.small {
  display: flex;
  width: 195px;
  height: 195px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"><span>Bob</span></div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="small"><span>Kate</span></div>
    <div class="small"><span>Nick</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="small"><span>Jane</span></div>
    <div class="small"><span>Fred</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/CodeCabbie/1xvjeo3p/44/

Answer (score 2):

Using fixed width (`width: 195px;`) for the small boxes using the `.small` class seems strange, and would explain why those columns do not shrink as the window resizes.

A combination of:

- [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) for the small boxes
- [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property on the columns

That would allow *all* columns to distribute the remaining space accordingly.

(Actually, [Michael Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-benjamin)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76095977/6309) is simpler)

Something like this example: https://jsfiddle.net/ko4Lszdy/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* Small columns will take 1/6 of the available space */
  max-width: 200px;
}

.big {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 2;
  /* Big column will take 2/3 of the available space */
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.small {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  /* Allow the small boxes to grow/shrink as needed */
  height: 195px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"><span>Bob</span></div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="small"><span>Kate</span></div>
    <div class="small"><span>Nick</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="small"><span>Jane</span></div>
    <div class="small"><span>Fred</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Move the `width: 195px` from `.small` to `.column`.

---

### Explanation

The second and third columns aren't shrinking because they're not sized in the primary flex container (`.container`). They're sized within a nested container (`.column`), which is beyond the reach of `flex-shrink`.

---

### Code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 195px;  /* new */
}

.big {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}

.small {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  /* width: 195px; */
  height: 195px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big"><span>Bob</span></div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="small"><span>Kate</span></div>
    <div class="small"><span>Nick</span></div>
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="small"><span>Jane</span></div>
    <div class="small"><span>Fred</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/q7xphdse/)

Comment: I agree your solution seems simpler and more to the point than mine. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not essential to use a `flexbox`, it is better to create all this using a `grid` layout. As a bonus, you will get a more concise and understandable code:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  /* optional */
  grid-gap: 5px;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
}

.big {
  grid-row: span 2;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
}

.small {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="big">Bob</div>
  <div class="small">Kate</div>
  <div class="small">Nick</div>
  <div class="small">Jane</div>
  <div class="small">Fred</div>
</div>
```